# Merge two unequal series in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, series

I have two series that are unequal in terms of length. (Date is index)

s1:

```
2006-03-25      35.27
2006-03-26      35.22
2006-03-28      35.25
2006-04-04      35.29
2006-04-05      35.46
2006-04-06      35.21
2006-04-08      35.32
2006-04-10      35.77
```

s2:

```
2006-03-25      1800
2006-03-26      1800
2006-03-27      1800
2006-03-28      1800
2006-03-29      1800
2006-03-30      1800
2006-03-31      1800
2006-04-01      2555
2006-04-02      2555
2006-04-03      2555
2006-04-04      2555
2006-04-05      2555
2006-04-06      2555
2006-04-07      2555
2006-04-08      2555
2006-04-09      2555
2006-04-10      2555
```

The series should be merged such that the value of each missing day in `s1` is the value of previous day.

The output should be like this:

```
2006-03-25      35.27      1800
2006-03-26      35.22      1800
2006-03-27      35.22      1800
2006-03-28      35.25      1800
2006-03-29      35.25      1800
2006-03-30      35.25      1800
2006-03-31      35.25      1800
2006-04-01      35.25      2555
2006-04-02      35.25      2555
2006-04-03      35.25      2555
2006-04-04      35.29      2555
2006-04-05      35.46      2555
2006-04-06      35.21      2555
2006-04-07      35.21      2555
2006-04-08      35.32      2555
2006-04-09      35.32      2555
2006-04-10      35.77      2555
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make them pandas data frame and then use merge method of pandas. it mean outer join for two dataset.after that use bfill() for fill nan values. it means fill backward missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=['date', 'vol1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(s2, columnd=['date', 'vol2'])

result = df1.merge(df2, left_on='date', right_on='date', how='outer')
result['vol2'] = result['vol2'].bfill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing:

```
# Use clipboard to create s1 as a pd.Series
s1 = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=[0], names=['s1']).squeeze()

# Use clipboard to create s2 as a pd.Series
s2 = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=[0], names=['s2']).squeeze()
```

Let's reindex s1 to match s2 and then fill forward the NaN with previous values.

```
df_out = pd.concat([s1.reindex_like(s2).ffill(), s2], axis=1)
df_out
```

Output:

```
               s1    s2
2006-03-25  35.27  1800
2006-03-26  35.22  1800
2006-03-27  35.22  1800
2006-03-28  35.25  1800
2006-03-29  35.25  1800
2006-03-30  35.25  1800
2006-03-31  35.25  1800
2006-04-01  35.25  2555
2006-04-02  35.25  2555
2006-04-03  35.25  2555
2006-04-04  35.29  2555
2006-04-05  35.46  2555
2006-04-06  35.21  2555
2006-04-07  35.21  2555
2006-04-08  35.32  2555
2006-04-09  35.32  2555
2006-04-10  35.77  2555
```